# events not firing after re-render in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone-routing

I am facing a problem while trying to click submit after re-render.

This is my view:

```
ShareHolderInfoView = Backbone.View.extend( {
template : 'shareholderinfo',
initialize: function() {
    this.model = new ShareHolderInfoModel();
},
render : function() {
    $.get("shareholderinfo.html", function(template) {
        var html = $(template);
        that.$el.html(html);
    });

    //context.loadViews.call(this);
    return this;
},
events:{
    "change input":"inputChanged",
    "change select":"selectionChanged",
    "click input[type=submit]":"showModel"
},
inputChanged:function(event){
    var field = $(event.currentTarget);
    var data ={};
    data[field.attr('id')] = field.val();
    this.model.set(data);
},
showModel:function(){
    console.log(this.model.attributes);
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.model.toJSON()));
}
});
```

This is my Router

```
var shareholderInfo,  accountOwnerInfo;

App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes:{
        'share':'share',
        'joint':'joint'
    },
    share:function(){

        $("#subSection").empty();
        if(!shareholderInfo){
            shareholderInfo = new ShareHolderInfoView();
            $("#subSection").append(shareholderInfo.render().el);
        } else{
            $("#subSection").append(shareholderInfo.$el);
        }
    },
    joint:function(random){
        $("#subSection").empty();
        if(!accountOwnerInfo){
            accountOwnerInfo = new AccountOwnerInfoView();
            $("#subSection").append(accountOwnerInfo.render().el);
        } else{
            $("#subSection").append(accountOwnerInfo.$el);
        }
    }
});
```

This is my HTML a div with  id='subSection'.

if I check in console, I can able to see the events bound to that view.

```
Object {change input: "inputChanged", change select: "selectionChanged", click input[type=submit]: "showModel"}
```

But its not calling that showModel function afer i click submit. Please help.

Comment: is your submit button inside your view's el?

Answer (score 5):

Your fundamental problem is that you're improperly reusing views.

From the [fine manual](http://api.jquery.com/empty/):

> **.empty()**
>
> **Description**: *Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.*
>   [...]
>   To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from the child elements before removing the elements themselves.

So when you say:

```
$("#subSection").empty();
```

you're not just clearing out the contents of `#subSection`, you're also removing all event handlers attached to anything inside `#subSection`. In particular, you'll remove any event handlers bound to `accountOwnerInfo.el` or `shareholderInfo.el` (depending on which one is already inside `#subSection`).

Reusing views is usually more trouble than it is worth, your views should be lightweight enough that you can destroy and recreate them as needed. The proper way to destroy a view is to call [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) on it. You could rewrite your router to look more like this:

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'share':'share',
        'joint':'joint'
    },
    share: function() {
        this._setView(ShareHolderInfoView);
    },
    joint: function(random){
        this._setView(AccountOwnerInfoView);
    },
    _setView: function(view) {
        if(this.currentView)
            this.currentView.remove();
        this.currentView = new view();
        $('#subSection').append(this.currentView.render().el);
    }
});
```

If your views need any extra cleanup then you can override `remove` on them to clean up the extras and then chain to `Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this)` to call the default `remove`.

If for some reason you need to keep your views around, you could call [`delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) on them:

> **delegateEvents** `delegateEvents([events])`
>
> Uses jQuery's `on` function to provide declarative callbacks for DOM events within a view. If an **events** hash is not passed directly, uses `this.events` as the source.

and you'd say things like:

```
$("#subSection").append(shareholderInfo.$el);
shareholderInfo.delegateEvents();
```

instead of just:

```
$("#subSection").append(shareholderInfo.$el);
```

I'd strongly recommend that you treat your views and cheap ephemeral objects: destroy them to remove them from the page, create new ones when they need to go on the page.

Comment: Great answer.  I'm surprised it only had one upvote when I got here.

Comment: @RyanOre: Thanks. I'm pretty sure I've written several versions of this answer but I can never find the duplicates, maybe no one else can find them either :)